# How can I move KDE Plasma taskbar to the top?

Tags: kde, taskbar

Is there any way to move Plasma Taskbar to the top of the screen? Currently it is at the bottom which makes it look like Windows.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In KDE Plasma a panel can be moved to a different screen edge by first enabling the configuration mode by clicking the settings button in the corner of the panel:

[image: Click the settings button]

Next drag the area that says "Screen Edge" to where you want the panel on the screen, such as the top:

[image: Drag the screen edge]

Comment: McMojave light? Can you share your configuration please. Mine looks all banged up. The panels don't have borders and they just look like white overlay. Maybe I did something wrong